# The downloaded files at the beginning of the execution in angular?

Tags: angular, frontend

I'm beginner in angular, I use **`ng serve`**, the application is running, but I have a question, what are the downloaded files at the beginning of the execution ?.
is the file **app.module** ?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser (or Cmd-alt-I on MacOS). Then go to the "Network" panel. Refresh your page. There: you have the files that are downloaded. TypeScript files are compiled to JS files, which are bundled together, and with the templates, too. Those bundles are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is generated by angular-cli, the entry point is located in `src/main.ts`, in that file, you could see angular will invoke 
`platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(RootModule);` to bootstrap your app